# How to pass the data into constructor using JNI

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I want to pass the integer value into student class constructor with the help of the JNI but may not get expected output what's wrong with me please can anybody refer this code and guide me.


**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    private int age;

    public Student(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

**StudentActivity.java**

```
public class StudentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    protected Student student;

    public static native Student getStudentInfo();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student);
        student = getStudentInfo();
        Log.d("TAG_DATA",String.valueOf(student.getAge()));
    }
}
```

**student.cpp**

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_kishandonga_jni_1expriment_Design_StudentActivity_getStudentInfo(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                          jclass type) {

    jclass fStudentClass = env->FindClass("com/kishandonga/jni_expriment/Model/Student");
    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(fStudentClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject nStdClass = env->NewObject(fStudentClass, constructor, 13);
    env->CallVoidMethod(nStdClass, constructor);

    return nStdClass;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

**student.cpp**

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_kishandonga_jni_1expriment_Design_StudentActivity_getStudentInfo(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                          jclass type) {

    jclass fStudentClass = env->FindClass("com/kishandonga/jni_expriment/Model/Student");
    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(fStudentClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject nStdClass = env->NewObject(fStudentClass, constructor, 13);
    // remove this
    // env->CallVoidMethod(nStdClass, constructor);
    return nStdClass;
}
```